# Need help on query builder and twig Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to do a private message functionnality.

**My goal is:**
a authenticated user go to the messages url, where he can see: every people he sent or received a message from, with every conversation grouped by the user, with the last message shown and the date of the last message.

**My problem is:** I actually retrieved the messages, but I can't find a way to only show the user one time (for example, if you sent the recipient a message, and he sent you one, the conversation is displayed two times, one for when you sent him a message, and one when he sent you one.)

I don't really know how to explain this clearly, but I want to do something like twitter/messages.

[Database table structure image, with the foreign keys linked to user_id in user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22uFL.png)

What I tried:

- Repository:

```
     /**
     * @return Message[] Returns an array of Message objects
     */
    public function findByUser($user)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->where('m.sender = :user')
            ->orWhere('m.recipient = :user')
            ->groupBy('m.recipient')
            ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

- Controller:

```
#[Route('/messages', name: 'app_messages')]
    public function index(MessageRepository $messageRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('messages/index.html.twig', [
            'messages' => $messageRepository->findByUser($this->getUser()),
            'controller_name' => 'MessagesController',
        ]);
    }
```

- Twig:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.sender.id == app.user.id %}
        {% set displayName = message.recipient %}
    {% elseif message.recipient.id == app.user.id %}
        {% set displayName = message.sender %}
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ path('app_messages_show', {id: message.id}) }}">
        <p>{{ displayName.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ displayName.username }}</p>
        <p>{{ message.date|date }}</p>
        <p>{{ message.content }}</p>
    </a>
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have any message </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Let's imagine every conversation is shown in a square div. Do you mean the same conversation appears twice (two squares), one with your last message and another for the other user's last message? Something like this? https://imgur.com/a/0o7chWi feel free to use it in your post if it helps

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/b2v74qh
Whenever you sent the last message or the other user did, it will be on the same block displaying the last message. Following your example, it would be "conversation with user2: last message sent" in a single div, like that: https://imgur.com/tSFzu38

Comment: You may have to add another layer before the messages. Call it Conversations (I think this is how FB does it). A user can have many conversations (OneToMany) and a conversation can have many messages (again, OneToMany). This way your db is structured and easy to work with. Just ideas for you...

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/wnr2A4aKnPU) might be of interest for you and give you a better idea on how to achieve what you want...

Comment: I kinda see what you mean, but after trying for hours I can't figure out how to do it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had good recommendations for changing the architectures of the database, and the best solution would be to to that. But there are ways to make it work if you really don't want to or can't change it. Because sometimes we just can't.

1. Edit the query:

You can create a custom column in your query :

```
->select('CASE WHEN m.sender = :user THEN m.recipient ELSE m.sender END AS correspondentUser')
```

And then handle the new column in results

2. Handle double messages in php:

You can work on your array of messages to remove unnecessary messages

```
$allMessages = $messageRepository->findByUser($this->getUser())
$correspondentsId = []
$messages = []
foreach($allMessages as $message){
  $correspondent = $message->getSender() === $this->getUser() ? $message->getRecipient : $messsage->getSender();
  if(!in_array($correspondent->getid(), $correspondentsId) ){
      $correspondentsId[] = $correspondent->getId();
      $messages[] = $message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when trying it, I get an error: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 41 near 'recipient ELSE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression."

Comment: Fixed it that way: ->select("CASE WHEN m.sender = :user THEN 'm.recipient' ELSE 'm.sender' END AS correspondentUser")
But now i get another error: Call to a member function getSender() on array on this line: $correspondent = $message->getSender() === $this->getUser() ? $message->getRecipient : $message->getSender();

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear in my answer : those are two different solutions. If you managed to do a proper query you will not need to handle double messages, findByUser will return an array with [[0 => message0, "correspondentUser" => user0], [0 => message1, "correspondentUser" => user1]] . Try to var_dump the content returned by findByUser to understand how to handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Rémi, it worked, I can finally sleep well :)